# Storing of std::weak_ptr<void> and using static_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, static-cast, weak-ptr

Will the reference count still work if storing `std::weak_ptr` with `static_pointer_cast`?

Here is a very simplifed example (note that the `SmallBox` and `BigBox` classes are almost exactly the same):

```
#define OWNER_SMALLBOX    1
#define OWNER_BIGBOX      2

class Object
{
    private:
        std::weak_ptr<void> owner;
        int ownerType;

    public:

        void doSomethingIfOwnerStillExist()
        {
            if(std::shared_ptr<void> ownerShared = owner.lock())
            {
                switch(ownerType)
                {
                    case OWNER_SMALLBOX:
                        std::shared_ptr<SmallBox> smallBox = std::static_pointer_cast<SmallBox>(ownerShared);
                    break;

                    case OWNER_BIGBOX:
                        std::shared_ptr<BigBox> bigBox = std::static_pointer_cast<BigBox>(ownerShared);
                    break;
                }//switch
            }
        }

        Object(std::shared_ptr<void> _owner, int _ownerType)
        {
            owner = _owner;
            ownerType = _ownerType;
        }
};

class SmallBox
{
    private:
        std::list< std::shared_ptr<Object> > objects;

    public:

        static void addObject(std::shared_ptr<SmallBox> _smallBox)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<void> owner = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(_smallBox);
            objects.push_back(std::make_shared<Object>(owner, OWNER_SMALL_BOX));
        }
};

class BigBox
{
    private:
        std::list< std::shared_ptr<Object> > objects;
    public:

        static void addObject(std::shared_ptr<BigBox> _bigBox)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<void> owner = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(_bigBox);
            objects.push_back(std::make_shared<Object>(owner, OWNER_BIGBOX));
        }
};
```

I know I can make the `SmallBox` and `BigBox` classes inherit from i.e. a `GeneralBox` class, and have the `void` type replaced with a `GeneralBox` type, but the `weak_ptr` can point to several other types aswell, making inheritance quite big and clumpsy.

I am curious if the `shared_ptr` still can keep track of the weak pointers converted to void.

Comment: I'd also suggest using something like `std::variant<std::weak_ptr<SmallBox>, std::weak_ptr<BigBox>>` instead, if you really need to cast back to the original type in `doSomethingIfOwnerStillExist`, because it will manage all the `ownerType` tracking that you do for you automatically. Or better, as you mentioned, use a base class with the interface that `doSomethingIfOwnerStillExist` will use. Since you have to track every possible type in `Object` already anyway, I don't see how adding the interface to each of the classes instead would be more complex.

Comment: I will look up std::variant. I am sorry I could not reduce the example, I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you are asking whether `std::static_pointer_cast` will return a `std::shared_ptr` sharing ownership with the argument that it is called on.

The answer to this is yes.

`owner` in `addObject` will share ownership with `addObject`'s function parameter and `owner` in object will refer to the same control block, as will `ownerShared` and `smallBox`, `bigBox` in `doSomethingIfOwnerStillExist`.

Note however that the `shared_ptr`'s that are stored in `objects` are completely unrelated, because they are initialized with calls to `std::make_shared` creating a new `Object`s that will be owned only by `objects`.

The `std::static_pointer_cast` would be pretty useless if it didn't return an instance sharing ownership with the argument, because it would inevitable lead to a double delete of the managed pointer, if it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to add the created object to the list in the example. It will be stored in the 'Box' classes.

Comment: Note that these pseudo "casts" are particular cases of the creation of an aliasing `shared_ptr` via the "aliasing constructor". You can even have an owning smart ptr to a member subobject, or an array element, or any object owned by object "co-owned" by the `shared_ptr`.